# Min, max length and show submit button not working with numpad

Tags: javascript

I created a password pin page, where users will have to insert their password, needed it to be like a POS NUMPAD

I'm trying to get the condition stated in the javascript to work.

Rule:
Do not show submit button when the minimum input isn't up to 4

it doesn't work when i use the numpad to input the number, but works when i input the number without the numpad.

Please can someone help me correct this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);

$('input').on('keyup',function()
{
    var input_val = $("#cc-pin").val();
 
    var minLength = $("#cc-pin").attr( 'minlength' );
 
    if(input_val != '' && input_val.length >= minLength)
    {
        $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false);
    }
    else
    {
        $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , true);
    }
});

});




 function addNumber(element){
  document.getElementById('cc-pin').value = document.getElementById('cc-pin').value+element.value;
}
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

element.style {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
} 

.fbutton { 
  background-color: #655F5F; /* #4CAF50 */
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 12px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="creditCard">
<div class="pinalert">
 <input id="cc-pin" style="text-align: center; color: red;" class="validate mbs date" name="cc-pin" type="password" maxlength="6" minlength="4" value="" data-mask="######" required>
        <label for="cc-pin"> </label><br /><br /> 

    <input id="cc-pin" type="button" class="fbutton" name="1" value="1" id="1" onClick=addNumber(this); />
  <input id="cc-pin" type="button" class="fbutton" name="2" value="2" id="2" onClick=addNumber(this); />
  <input id="cc-pin" type="button" class="fbutton" name="3" value="3" id="3" onClick=addNumber(this); /> <br /><br>
  <input id="cc-pin" type="button" class="fbutton" name="4" value="4" id="4" onClick=addNumber(this); />
  <input id="cc-pin" type="button" class="fbutton" name="5" value="5" id="5" onClick=addNumber(this); />
  <input id="cc-pin" type="button" class="fbutton" name="6" value="6" id="6" onClick=addNumber(this); /> <br /><br>
  <input id="cc-pin" type="button" class="fbutton" name="7" value="7" id="7" onClick=addNumber(this); />
  <input id="cc-pin" type="button" class="fbutton" name="8" value="8" id="8" onClick=addNumber(this); />
  <input id="cc-pin" type="button" class="fbutton" name="9" value="9" id="9" onClick=addNumber(this); /> <br /><br>
  <input id="cc-pin" type="button" class="fbutton" name="0" value="0" id="0" onClick=addNumber(this); />


</div>

                    
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-medium wide-sm center">SUBMIT</button>


                            
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
```

Comment: `minLength` would be a string. You'll need to parse it to integer before comparing the length.

Comment: Just my point of view with the best intentions: **if this is an enterprise project**, then the best way to do this is to not do this. As a user, I have always been irritated by such solutions, because it is unnatural and provides unusual, slow and inconvenient UX. As a software engineer, I always refused to do this (I've been asked to do the same in one bank in the past), because it doesn't bring any improvement. Keyloggers are smart enough to track mouse clicks or content inside password fields.

Comment: do some search about `parseInt()` and also, if you want it to work when the user is clicking on the buttons, use `click` instead of `keyup`

Comment: Also, you can not have same `id` for multiple elements. The `id` should be **unique** for each element.

Comment: @PrerakSola i did it like that so i don't get confuse, still a novice with javascript... please can u help me with the corrections?

Comment: @PrerakSola please, im not yet good with javascript, can you help me with the correction of what your saying: codepen.io/devniche/pen/zeBrxY

Comment: @CalvinNunes the click made only the minlength with the numpad display the button, but made direct input without numpad not to work $('input').on('click',function(

Comment: you'll need a listener for input by keyboard numpad and another one for clicking the HTML numpad`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your numpad buttons do not trigger the `$('input').on('keyup',function()`, thus, the `input_val.length >= minLength` validation is never triggered. Seperate your validation logic in a seperate function and have both your `on('keyup')` and `addNumber()` function execute it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", true);

  $("input").on("keyup", function() {
    validateInput();
  });
});

function validateInput() {
  var input_val = $("#cc-pin").val();

  var minLength = $("#cc-pin").attr("minlength");

  if (input_val != "" && input_val.length >= minLength) {
    $('button[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('button[type="submit"]').attr("disabled", true);
  }
}

function addNumber(element) {
  document.getElementById("cc-pin").value =
    document.getElementById("cc-pin").value + element.value;
  validateInput();
}
```

Comment: wow... this did the magic, but the numpad doesnt respect the maxlength condition of 6

<input id="cc-pin" style="text-align: center; color: red;" class="validate mbs date" name="cc-pin" type="password" maxlength="6" minlength="4" value="" data-mask="######" required>

Comment: @DevNiche The maxlength condition is performed by the browser, not by javascript. As such, javascript doesn't know it shouldn't append another number when it's length is already 6. Nowadays almost all browsers support the maxlength attribute, but if you want to enforce a maximum length, you should add another condition in your addNumber function (or even better, in the submit function) like `if (document.getElementById("cc-pin").value.length < 6) ...`

Comment: Adding that, won't it result adding an else condition?